# Using "remove" or "pop" to delete elements from heapq

Tags: python, heap

Let's say I've built a heap by using `heappush` to push 10 numbers onto the heap.

Now I want to remove certain elements, the nth element or a particular number.

Since the heap is just a list, I can use `pop(i)` or `remove` to do that.

After using `pop()` and `remove()`, is the list still a heap or do I have to `heapify` the list again?

Comment: If you find yourself modifying the underlying data structure on a regular basis, you might reconsider your approach. I've found that violating the heap usually means that either I don't really need a heap, or that I can accomplish what I need without violating the heap contract.

Answer (score 1):

Both operations can violate the heapq invariant, so yes, you should heapify after either operation.